# PHP die() vs. echo

Tags: php

Can anyone please tell me why line 1 works (returns 35434), but line 2 doesn't (returns blank)?

1. `echo $_FILES['userfile']['size'];`
2. `die ($_FILES['userfile']['size']);`

Thanks!

Comment: Are these two in the exact same spot or on two different pages? (Yes, it's a dumb question, but it's just to make sure.)

Answer (score 13):

[`die`](http://php.net/die) is equivalent to [`exit`](http://php.net/exit) and you'll notice that `exit` takes either an integer or a string as an argument.  In the case you pass an integer, then the program exits and returns that integer as its exit code.

`$_FILES['userfile']['size']` is an integer, not a string, so instead of outputting the message to the screen, it returns the size as the return code of the program.

A simple solution is to concatenate to an empty string to let the PHP compiler you want a string instead of an integer:

```
die('' . $_FILES['userfile']['size']);
```

Comment: Also note that the integer argument of die() / exit() cannot be higher than 254.

Answer (score 2):

I [answered this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825002/what-is-the-difference-between-echoexit-die-and-dieexit/5825405#5825405) a few hours ago, anyway the other answers are right.

As a workaround (if you need to do that), casting the integer to a string will do the trick:

```
die(strval($_FILES['userfile']['size'])); // or
die((string) $_FILES['userfile']['size']);
```

Answer (score 1):

`die()` only prints strings. ([See manual](https://www.php.net/die)) If you add some text in there it will work, for some reason. ;)