# Can I call die after echo with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to add some error checking inside my PHP script. Is it valid to do this:

```
if (!mkdir($dir, 0)) {
    $res->success = false;
    $res->error = 'Failed to create directory';
    echo json_encode($res);
    die;
}
```

Is there a better way to exit the script after encountering an error like this?

Comment: in ajax call, i normally use exit();

Comment: @racar there is no difference between `die` and `exit` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825002/what-is-the-difference-between-echoexit-die-and-dieexit [PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)

Comment: @Neal, you can do exit(1) but die will always return 0

Comment: @racar they are exactly the same! see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: i was wrong, but i still prefer exit. Die is too violent ^^ Thx Neal

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That looks fine to me.

You can even echo data in the `die` like so:

```
if (!mkdir($dir, 0)) {
    $res->success = false;
    $res->error = 'Failed to create directory';
    die(json_encode($res));
}
```

Comment: Just learned about the die(json_encode('whatever goes here'));  THANK YOU>

Answer (score 5):

Throwing a exception. Put code into a try catch block, and throw exception when you need.

Comment: Why use an exception when die is simpler? This is not the case where to use exceptions handler.

Comment: it's for separation of concerns. A low-level function should not deal with output. What if you now re-use the function as part of a console utility? Using exceptions allows you to handle the error at the appropriate layer.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has functions for [error triggering and handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php).

```
if (!mkdir($dir, 0)) {
    trigger_error('Failed to create directory', E_USER_ERROR)
}
```

When you do this the script will end. The message will be written to the configured error log and it will also be displayed when error_reporting is enabled.